# South African and Mozambican board games?

Tags: recommendations

As I love both traveling and board games, I always try to buy a local made game with roots from, or great popularity, in that specific country/region.
E.g. I got Shogi when I was in Japan, and Dominoes from a trip to Cuba.

Now I'm going to South Africa and Mozambique and would like to get my hands on a local game.

Do you know of any board games that are native to South Africa or Mozambique, besides different types of Mancala?

I already have a Mancala-type game called Omweso from Zambia, but I guess I wouldn't turn down a more original type Mancala from Mozambique if that's the only alternative.

Comment: Welcome to Board Games Stack Exchange! This looks like a recommendation question, which is not within the scope of questions defined in our [help center](http://boardgames.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). Recommendation questions usually become obsolete pretty quickly and it's hard to pick a "right" answer out of multiple people's suggestions. Still, we'll be happy to answer any other questions you have about board games!

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking for localised versions of games through Africa another option to the Mancala family are games of the Nine Men's Morris family, which potentially migrated down through Africa at the height of the Roman empire.

For South Africa there is **Muravava** or **Umlabalaba**, which is closer to Twelve Men's Morris in that there are more moves available.
In Mozambique you'll find **Gulugufe**, which is played on two intersecting triangles. There is also **Ntchuva**, which is the local variant of Mancala.

Comment: This is great! Thanks. I definitely keep my eyes open for one of these games!

Answer (score 1):

I can reccomend 30 seconds. It is a SA boardgame in the more western approach. You used to get those in checkers supermarks and picnpays but Im not sure if they still sell them